# Can different cleanups be done conditionally in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

So, I have an `useEffect` like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if(foo) {
        // do something
        return () => { // cleanup function }
    }
}, [foo])
```

Here, the `cleanup` function is never called, even if `if` block is executed. But if I modify the effect to be:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if(foo) {
        // do something
    }
    return () => { // cleanup function }
}, [foo])
```

it works. 
So, is the cleanup done only if `return` is the last statement of `useEffect` or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand the question. Will cleanup be performed only if it is returned not from the conditional branches?

Comment: thats what exactly mentioned in the documentation. Please do take a look

Comment: Hi @tsuki, I was looking into this as well. I don't know why `cleanup` wasn't being called for you. I made an example codesandbox which proves that cleanup gets called within the conditional - https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-microservice-5895d?file=/src/App.tsx

It shows that clean up gets executed with the correct values before the new effect is called. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cleanup function is recreated every time the `useEffect` updater function is called. The current cleanup function would be called when the dependency changes (or on each render if no dependency), or before the component is unmounted. After the cleanup is called, the updater would be called, and a new cleanup function can be returned.

You can return a different function, or none at all, whenever the updater function is called.

For example, click the **Inc** button multiple times, and you can see in the console that the cleanup function exists only for even `counter` numbers, because it's returned conditionally.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Demo = () => {
  const [counter, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Effect ${counter}`);
    
    if(counter % 2 === 0) {
      return () => console.log(`Cleanup ${counter}`);
    }
  }, [counter]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Counter: {counter}</p>
      
      <button onClick={() => setCount(counter + 1)}>Inc</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  root
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; left: 50% !important; max-height: unset !important; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Sometimes, nesting the cleanup function inside a condition might be confusing. Another option is to always return a cleanup function, and put the logic inside it:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if(foo) {
        // do something
    }
    
    return () => { 
      if(foo) {
        // cleanup something
      }
    }
}, [foo])
```

And you can see in this example, the result is the same:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Demo = () => {
  const [counter, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Effect ${counter}`);

    return () => {
      if(counter % 2 === 0) {
        console.log(`Cleanup ${counter}`);
      }    
    };
  }, [counter]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Counter: {counter}</p>
      
      <button onClick={() => setCount(counter + 1)}>Inc</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  root
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; left: 50% !important; max-height: unset !important; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you return a function in the callback passed to `useEffect`, the returned function will be called before the component is removed from the UI.

Normally we do cleanups in the `componentWillUnmount` for class based component. Let's say you want to create an event listener on `componentDidMount` and clean it up on `componentDidUnmount`.Like class based with hooks the code will be combined into one callback function.

For cleanup define like this -example

```
useEffect(()=>{
        let interval = setInterval(()=>{
           // do something 
         }),1000}
    return () => { clearInterval(interval) }
}, [foo])
```

For better understanding check official [Effects with Cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: This is what I do but the cleanup function is called before the setInterval to finish. I am loading a progress bar in the setInterval. How can I call the clearInterval method only when the operations from the setInterval are done ?